# Java: What is the best way to write object data members to a file?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, randomaccessfile, storing-data

I'm in the middle of a Java project where one of the things I need to do to make it work is to write and read objects from disk. Specifically, I need to write and then later load a given object's data members from a single `RandomAccessFile` with fixed-sized records for each object. This file represents a partition with fixed sized disk blocks.

Now what I've done is to explicitly convert every data member to bytes using `ByteBuffer`. I then wrote these to file, allowing the data to be reloaded later to instantiate a new object with identical values for its data members. The thing I don't like about this approach is that every single data member must be explicitly converted and put into the `ByteBuffer` and then written. Loading just does the opposite, converting all the bytes back and storing them in an object of the appropriate type.

The approach I used above just seems overly convoluted. Is there a better way, easier way? What I was thinking of is something similar to what you can do I do in C++. In the past I've stored and reloaded object data from fixed-size indexed records pretty easily using a pointer to the object and then writing all the bytes from there with `ofstream` (or similar), after casting the pointer to `const char *` using `reinterpret_cast`. Loading the file with `ifstream` (or similar) was just as simple, simply using index * `sizeOf(Foo)` to calculate the file pointer offset and then seeking before reading into memory from file.

Is there something similar to this approach in Java?

Comment: Your C++ approach would fail miserably if the types are not POD types.  You need to read up on object serialization.

Comment: How do you store an object that has a list/array of related objects in fixed-sized records?

Comment: Random access of these objects seems like a task that would be more conveniently solved by writing them to a database, rather than files on a disk. Is there some constraint that makes this difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) which allows you to serialize arbitrary (but must implement `Serializable`) objects to a byte array (or in this case stream) which can then be written to disk. That by itself won't support your random access needs, but it will be a good part of the solution that doesn't require custom adapters.